# Session in firebase analytics control

Tags: android

In google analytics we used have Dashboard data where its shows the total users and sessions, and also it lists down session on the basis of devices and demographic regions. I am trying to find out similar in `Firebase` analytics but is unable to see any. Can anyone kindly guide me where i can see session related data in `Firebase` analytics console.